# Fragment Ipv6 packet using Pcap.Net

Tags: c#, fragment, packet, pcap.net

So i found this solution for `IpV4`:

```
private IEnumerable<Packet> SplitPacket(Packet packet, int numberOfFragments)
{
    IpV4Datagram ipV4Datagram = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;

    if (ipV4Datagram.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Tcp || ipV4Datagram.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Udp)
    {
        EthernetLayer ethernet = (EthernetLayer)packet.Ethernet.ExtractLayer();
        ILayer layer = packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
        IpV4Layer ipV4Layer = (IpV4Layer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.ExtractLayer();
        ipV4Layer.HeaderChecksum = null;
        DateTime packetTimestamp = packet.Timestamp;
        PayloadLayer payload = (PayloadLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Payload.ExtractLayer(); //extract the data
        int totalLength = payload.Length;
        int partialLength = totalLength / numberOfFragments; //split data into smaller segments
        partialLength = (partialLength / 8) * 8; //make sure it's divisible with 8
        if (partialLength == 0)
            partialLength = 8;
        //(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Fragmentation_and_reassembly)
        ushort offset = 0; //send one by one

        while (offset < totalLength)
        {
            int fragmentLength = partialLength; //get length for this fragment
            IpV4FragmentationOptions options = IpV4FragmentationOptions.MoreFragments;

            if (offset + fragmentLength >= totalLength) //is this the last fragment ? trim length if needed
            {
                options = IpV4FragmentationOptions.None;
                fragmentLength = totalLength - offset;
            }

            byte[] newBuffer = ipV4Datagram.Payload.ToArray(); //copy the actual data into a new buffer
            PayloadLayer newPayload = new PayloadLayer { Data = new Datagram(newBuffer, offset, fragmentLength) };
            ipV4Layer.Fragmentation = new IpV4Fragmentation(options, offset); //change IP layer fragmentation options
            Packet newPacket = null;

            if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Tcp)
            {
                TcpLayer tcpLayer = (TcpLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Tcp.ExtractLayer();
                tcpLayer.Checksum = null;
                newPacket = PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer, newPayload);
            }
            else if (packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Protocol == IpV4Protocol.Udp)
            {
                UdpLayer udpLayer = (UdpLayer)packet.Ethernet.IpV4.Udp.ExtractLayer();
                udpLayer.Checksum = null;
                newPacket = PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, udpLayer, newPayload);
            }

            yield return newPacket;
            //yield return PacketBuilder.Build(packetTimestamp, ethernet, ipV4Layer, tcpLayer, newPayload); //return
            offset += (ushort)fragmentLength; //next offset
        }
    }
}
```

And since `Ipv6Layer` does not contain several fields like in `IpV4layer` for example `IpV4FragmentationOptions` i wonder how `Fragmentation` is implemented over `IpV6`

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet#Fragmenting):

> **Fragmentation**
>
> Unlike in IPv4, IPv6 routers never fragment IPv6 packets. Packets
>   exceeding the size of the maximum transmission unit of the destination
>   link are dropped and this condition is signaled by a Packet too Big
>   ICMPv6 type 2 message to the originating node, similarly to the IPv4
>   method when the Don't Fragment bit is set.
>
> End nodes in IPv6 are expected to perform path MTU discovery to
>   determine the maximum size of packets to send, and the upper-layer
>   protocol is expected to limit the payload size. However, if the
>   upper-layer protocol is unable to do so, the sending host may use the
>   Fragment extension header in order to perform end-to-end fragmentation
>   of IPv6 packets. Any data link layer conveying IPv6 data must be
>   capable of delivering an IP packet containing 1280 bytes without the
>   need to invoke end-to-end fragmentation at the IP layer.
>
> **Fragmenting**
>
> A packet containing a fragment of an original (larger) packet consists
>   of two parts: the unfragmentable part of the original packet (which is
>   the same for all fragments), and a piece of the fragmentable part of
>   the original packet, identified by a Fragment Offset. The Fragment
>   Offset of the first ("leftmost") fragment is 0.
>
> The unfragmentable part of a packet consists of the fixed header and
>   some of the extension headers of the original packet (if present): all
>   extension headers up to and including the Routing extension header, or
>   else the Hop-by-Hop extension header. If neither extension headers are
>   present, the unfragmentable part is just the fixed header.
>
> The Next Header value of the last (extension) header of the
>   unfragmentable part is set to 44 to indicate that a Fragment extension
>   header follows. After the Fragment extension header a fragment of the
>   rest of the original packet follows.
>
> The first fragment(s) hold the rest of the extension headers (if
>   present). After that the rest of the payload follows. Each fragment is
>   a multiple of 8 octets in length, except the last fragment.
>
> Each Fragment extension header has its M flag set to 1 (indicating
>   more fragments follow), except the last, whose flag is set to 0.
>
> **Reassembly**
>
> The original packet is reassembled by the receiving node by collecting
>   all fragments and placing each fragment at the right offset and
>   discarding the Fragment extension headers of the packets that carried
>   them. Packets containing fragments need not arrive in sequence; they
>   will be rearranged by the receiving node.
>
> If not all fragments are received within 60 seconds after receiving
>   the first packet with a fragment, reassembly of the original packet is
>   abandoned and all fragments are discarded. If the first fragment was
>   received (which contains the fixed header), a Time Exceeded message
>   (ICMPv6 type 3, code 1) is returned to the node originating the
>   fragmented packet, if the packet was discarded for this reason.
>
> Receiving hosts must make a best-effort attempt to reassemble
>   fragmented IP datagrams that, after reassembly, contain up to 1500
>   bytes. Hosts are permitted to make an attempt to reassemble fragmented
>   datagrams larger than 1500 bytes, but they are also permitted to
>   silently discard any datagram after it becomes apparent that the
>   reassembled packet would be larger than 1500 bytes. Therefore, senders
>   should avoid sending fragmented IP datagrams with a total reassembled
>   size larger than 1500 bytes, unless they have previous assurance that
>   the receiver is capable of reassembling such large datagrams.
>
> **Security**
>
> Research has shown that the use of fragmentation can be leveraged to
>   evade network security controls. As a result, RFC 7112 requires that
>   the first fragment of an IPv6 packet contains the entire IPv6 header
>   chain, such that some very pathological fragmentation cases are
>   forbidden. Additionally, as a result of research on the evasion of
>   RA-Guard in RFC 7113, RFC 6980 has deprecated the use of fragmentation
>   with Neighbor Discovery, and discouraged the use of fragmentation with
>   Secure Neighbor Discovery (SEND).